# Python: Why Does my while loop keep looping

Tags: python, loops

```
def guess():
    while True:
        try:
            guess = raw_input("Guess your letter")
            if len(guess) != 1 or guess.isdigit() == True:
                print "Please guess again"
            if len(guess) == 1 and  guess.isdigit() == False:
                guessed.append = guess
                return guess
                break
        except StandardError:
            pass

print guess()
```

this loop keeps repeating no matter what value I put in the raw input. Why???

Comment: probably because `guessed.append = guess` raises an error.  Can't be sure because you don't tell us what `guessed` is

Comment: Other people have diagnosed your problem already, but it's probably worth noticing that your `break` statement is unreachable (and therefore worthless).

Comment: `try`,`except` statements often hide real errors. Why are you using one? it seems like you already have error catching in the form of your `if` statements?

Answer (score 2):

Because `guessed.append = guess` wil raise an error every time `len(guess) == 1 and  guess.isdigit() == False` is `True` and then the control will go to the `except` block
which is going to restart the loop again.

If you've defined `guessed` somewhere in your code then I think you probably wanted to do this:

```
guessed.append(guess)
```

Otherwise define `guessed` first.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you try to execute the line `guessed.append = guess` you raise a `StandardError`, so the line telling you to `return guess` is never executed.

To fix it you should define `guessed` outside the function, and correct the line to `guessed.append(guess)`.

Also note that the line `break` right after `return guess` would never be executed even if you fixed this bug.